# Проблема с открытием данных в Excel: ошибка в части содержимого в книге (openspout)

Tags: php, excel

Использую **php8.2**, "**openspout/openspout**: **^4.17.2**". Все тесты проходят удачно и все генерируется в Excel нормально. Но на продакшен-сервере иногда открываются данные с ошибкой:

**Ошибка в части содержимого в книге**

[image: ошибка в части содержимого в книге]

Не могу найти причину, почему это происходит. Все HTML-сущности обрабатываю через htmlspecialchars_decode(). Сколько не провожу тестов, не могу поймать ошибку из-за чего это происходит. Может быть, у вас есть варианты, как узнать, почему и где ошибка. Есть сломанный файл Excel, но не могу его скинуть из-за конфиденциальности.

Comment: Пробовали нажать кнопку "Да"?

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: <recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
<logFileName>error191640_01.xml</logFileName>
<summary>Обнаружены ошибки в файле "C:\Users\USER\Downloads\Desktop\поиск_2024_03_26_ID_3579248декабрь.xlsx"</summary>
<additionalInfo>
<info>Была выполнена проверка на уровне файла с последующим восстановлением файла. Некоторые фрагменты документа могли быть восстановлены либо удалены.</info>
</additionalInfo>
<removedRecords>
<removedRecord>Удаленные записи: Формула из части /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml</removedRecord>
</removedRecords>
</recoveryLog>

Comment: Вот такую ошибку пишет, что сверху находится

Comment: Кнопку да то я нажму и все отлично, но мне надо понять почему такая ошибка появляется, может кто то сталкивался и мог каким то образом понять где ошибка в EXCEL?

Comment: скачайте этот файл на комп, откройте архиваторим (7zip например), найдите xml из сообщения об ошибке, откройте xml редактором и посмотрите, что там в реальности вписано. Дальше уже делайте выводы, где ошибка при генерации

Comment: @DmitryKozlov спасибо за совет, посмотрю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что в ячейке в начале строки стоял знак '=', Excel думает что это формула.

Его необходимо экранировать, разные способы, которые я нашел в интернете, не помогли, например добавить символ '(апостроф), мне помогло добавление табуляции или пробела в начало.
Пример:

```
$cellValue = " " . $cellValue;
```

Или обрезать вначале через ltrim

```
$cellValue = ltrim($cellValue,'=');
```